# electron javascript separate classes in different files

Tags: javascript, electron

For simplicity I want to keep my main.js clear and outsource classes for the different windows in separate files. I have no idea how to reference the files.
It should look like this

```
//main.js 

const electron = require('electron');
const { app } = electron;

app.on('ready', () => {
  createWindow(); // 
});
```

And the second file with my main page:

```
// mainPage.js

const { BrowserWindow } = require('electron').remote

function createWindow() {
  let win = new BrowserWindow({ width: 800, height: 600 });
  win.loadFile('mainPage.html');
  /* more code related to that page */
}
```

But electron doesn't recognize my mainPage.js file, usually in JavaScript this is no problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So at the end of `mainPage.js`:

```
module.exports = { createWindow }
```

and at the top of `main.js`

```
const { createWindow } = require("./mainPage") //assuming files in same dir
```

See https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_modules for more information about how this works.

Comment: That was exactly what I was looking for. Thanks @spender